# Replace 2>&1 in the PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

We use the below function in one of our PowerShell scripts. Can someone explain what "2>&1" means here? Is there any equivalent full cmdlet to replace this value?

```
function InvExp {
    param (
        [string]$cmd
    )
        $er = (invoke-expression $cmd) 2>&1
        if($er.Exception){
            throw $er.Exception
        }
}
```

Comment: "Redirect stderr to stdout" or in PowerShell, "Redirect Error Stream to Success Stream", that's what `2>&1` means. And the other way around would be using a `try` / `catch` statement

Comment: try catch will not work with invoke-expression command. that is the reason we are using this function

Comment: not sure what you mean, `try { iex 'asd' } catch { 'hello' }` works perfectly fine

Comment: You are essentially turning even non-critical errors of `$cmd` such as produced by `Write-Error`, into exceptions, but the way you are doing it, you are losing PowerShell-specific error information from the error record `$er`, such as the script stacktrace.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon.. Please check below command

try { iex -Command "Get-Process test" } catch { 'hello' }

Comment: I see what you mean, easiest way I could imagine to get around this would be: `try { & {[CmdletBinding()]param() iex -Command "Get-Process test" } -EA 1 } catch { 'hello' }`

Comment: Or try catch the invocation of your function instead Or, if you're going to invoke and actual cmdlet don't use `Invoke-Expression`, tbh don't see the point of your function in a real world example

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon... get-process cmdlet works.. But this cmdlet does not works...

try { & {[CmdletBinding()]param() invoke-expression -Command "Get-CsOnlineUser wrongsip@test.com" } -EA 1 } catch { write-host test}

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really see the point of a function that is used to invoke an expression that invokes a cmdlet. Besides, if you're passing an expression that contains the invocation of a cmdlet you could mind as well add `-EA 1` to the cmdlet invocation itself: `try { iex "Get-CsOnlineUser wrongsip@test.com -EA 1" } catch { 'something' }`

Answer (score 1):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) notes, **`2>&1`** is a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (`>`) that **redirects [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) number `2` (the *error* stream) into (`&`) stream number `1` (the *success* stream)**.

- When calling *external programs*, `2` in redirections refers to such a program's *stderr* output, and `1` (the default stream) to its *stdout* output.

**What your function in effect does is to promote *any* error** - irrespective of whether it is a *non*-terminating or a (statement-)*terminating* error - **to a *fatal* error** (***script*-terminating** aka runspace-terminating error).

However, I propose a ***simpler implementation***, which also avoids the use of [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), which is *generally* [to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), by instead requiring that a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) rather than a *string* be passed as an argument:

```
function Assert-NoError {
  param(
    [scriptblock] $cmd
  )
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  . $cmd
}
```

You would then invoke the function as follows, for example:

```
Assert-NoError { Get-Process test }
```

Note:

- `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` creates a *local* instance of the  the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference), and by setting it to `Stop` ensures that *any* error results in a *fatal* error by default.
- The above implementation has the added advantage that any *success* output that precedes an error is output before execution is aborted.